# How to load CSVs with timestamps in custom format?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hortonworks-data-platform, azure-hdinsight

I have a timestamp field in a csv file that I load to a dataframe using spark csv library. The same piece of code works on my local machine with Spark 2.0 version but  throws an error on Azure Hortonworks HDP 3.5 and 3.6.

I have checked and Azure HDInsight 3.5 is also using the same Spark version so I don't think it's a problem with Spark version.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
val sourceFile = "C:\\2017\\datetest"
val sourceSchemaStruct = new StructType()
  .add("EventDate",DataTypes.TimestampType)
  .add("Name",DataTypes.StringType)
val df = spark.read
  .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .option("header","true")
  .option("delimiter","|")
  .option("mode","FAILFAST")
  .option("inferSchema","false")
  .option("dateFormat","yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
  .schema(sourceSchemaStruct)
  .load(sourceFile)
```

The whole exception is as follows:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Timestamp format must be yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff]
  at java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(Timestamp.java:237)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.DateTimeUtils$.stringToTime(DateTimeUtils.scala:179)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.UnivocityParser$$anonfun$makeConverter$9$$anonfun$apply$13$$anonfun$apply$2.apply$mcJ$sp(UnivocityParser.scala:142)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.UnivocityParser$$anonfun$makeConverter$9$$anonfun$apply$13$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(UnivocityParser.scala:142)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.UnivocityParser$$anonfun$makeConverter$9$$anonfun$apply$13$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(UnivocityParser.scala:142)
  at scala.util.Try.getOrElse(Try.scala:79)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.UnivocityParser$$anonfun$makeConverter$9$$anonfun$apply$13.apply(UnivocityParser.scala:139)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.UnivocityParser$$anonfun$makeConverter$9$$anonfun$apply$13.apply(UnivocityParser.scala:135)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.UnivocityParser.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$csv$UnivocityParser$$nullSafeDatum(UnivocityParser.scala:179)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.UnivocityParser$$anonfun$makeConverter$9.apply(UnivocityParser.scala:135)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.UnivocityParser$$anonfun$makeConverter$9.apply(UnivocityParser.scala:134)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.UnivocityParser.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$csv$UnivocityParser$$convert(UnivocityParser.scala:215)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.UnivocityParser.parse(UnivocityParser.scala:187)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.UnivocityParser$$anonfun$5.apply(UnivocityParser.scala:304)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.UnivocityParser$$anonfun$5.apply(UnivocityParser.scala:304)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FailureSafeParser.parse(FailureSafeParser.scala:61)
  ... 27 more
```

The csv file has only one row as follows:

```
"EventDate"|"Name"
"2016/12/19 00:43:27.583"|"adam"
```

Answer (score 12):

**TL;DR** Use `timestampFormat` option (not `dateFormat`).

---

I've managed to reproduce it in the latest Spark version **2.3.0-SNAPSHOT** (built from the master).

```
// OS shell
$ cat so-43259485.csv
"EventDate"|"Name"
"2016/12/19 00:43:27.583"|"adam"

// spark-shell
scala> spark.version
res1: String = 2.3.0-SNAPSHOT

case class Event(EventDate: java.sql.Timestamp, Name: String)
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders
val schema = Encoders.product[Event].schema

scala> spark
  .read
  .format("csv")
  .option("header", true)
  .option("mode","FAILFAST")
  .option("delimiter","|")
  .schema(schema)
  .load("so-43259485.csv")
  .show(false)
17/04/08 11:03:42 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 7.0 (TID 7)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Timestamp format must be yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff]
    at java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(Timestamp.java:237)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.DateTimeUtils$.stringToTime(DateTimeUtils.scala:167)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.UnivocityParser$$anonfun$makeConverter$9$$anonfun$apply$17$$anonfun$apply$6.apply$mcJ$sp(UnivocityParser.scala:146)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.UnivocityParser$$anonfun$makeConverter$9$$anonfun$apply$17$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(UnivocityParser.scala:146)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.UnivocityParser$$anonfun$makeConverter$9$$anonfun$apply$17$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(UnivocityParser.scala:146)
    at scala.util.Try.getOrElse(Try.scala:79)
```

The [corresponding line in the Spark sources](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/util/DateTimeUtils.scala#L167) is the "root cause" of the issue:

```
Timestamp.valueOf(s)
```

Having read the [javadoc of Timestamp.valueOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-), you can learn that the argument should be:

> timestamp in format `yyyy-[m]m-[d]d hh:mm:ss[.f...]`. The fractional seconds may be omitted. The leading zero for mm and dd may also be omitted.

Note "The fractional seconds may be omitted" so let's cut it off by first loading the EventDate as a String and only after removing the unneeded fractional seconds convert it to Timestamp.

```
val eventsAsString = spark.read.format("csv")
  .option("header", true)
  .option("mode","FAILFAST")
  .option("delimiter","|")
  .load("so-43259485.csv")
```

It turns out that [for fields of `TimestampType` type](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/csv/UnivocityParser.scala#L134) Spark [uses `timestampFormat` option](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/csv/UnivocityParser.scala?utf8=%E2%9C%93#L138) first if defined and only if not uses [the code the uses `Timestamp.valueOf`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/csv/UnivocityParser.scala?utf8=%E2%9C%93#L142).

It turns out the fix is just to use `timestampFormat` option (not `dateFormat`!).

```
val df = spark.read
  .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .option("header","true")
  .option("delimiter","|")
  .option("mode","FAILFAST")
  .option("inferSchema","false")
  .option("timestampFormat","yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
  .schema(sourceSchemaStruct)
  .load(sourceFile)
scala> df.show(false)
+-----------------------+----+
|EventDate              |Name|
+-----------------------+----+
|2016-12-19 00:43:27.583|adam|
+-----------------------+----+
```

### Spark 2.1.0

Use schema inference in CSV using `inferSchema` option with your custom `timestampFormat`.

It's important to trigger schema inference using `inferSchema` for `timestampFormat` to take effect.

```
val events = spark.read
  .format("csv")
  .option("header", true)
  .option("mode","FAILFAST")
  .option("delimiter","|")
  .option("inferSchema", true)
  .option("timestampFormat", "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")
  .load("so-43259485.csv")

scala> events.show(false)
+-------------------+----+
|EventDate          |Name|
+-------------------+----+
|2016-12-19 00:43:27|adam|
+-------------------+----+

scala> events.printSchema
root
 |-- EventDate: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- Name: string (nullable = true)
```

---

#### "Incorrect" initial version left for learning purposes

```
val events = eventsAsString
  .withColumn("date", split($"EventDate", " ")(0))
  .withColumn("date", translate($"date", "/", "-"))
  .withColumn("time", split($"EventDate", " ")(1))
  .withColumn("time", split($"time", "[.]")(0))    // <-- remove millis part
  .withColumn("EventDate", concat($"date", lit(" "), $"time")) // <-- make EventDate right
  .select($"EventDate" cast "timestamp", $"Name")

scala> events.printSchema
root
 |-- EventDate: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- Name: string (nullable = true)
    events.show(false)

scala> events.show
+-------------------+----+
|          EventDate|Name|
+-------------------+----+
|2016-12-19 00:43:27|adam|
+-------------------+----+
```

### Spark 2.2.0

As of Spark 2.2 you can use `to_timestamp` function to do the string to timestamp conversion.

```
eventsAsString.select($"EventDate", to_timestamp($"EventDate", "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")).show(false)

scala> eventsAsString.select($"EventDate", to_timestamp($"EventDate", "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")).show(false)
+-----------------------+----------------------------------------------------+
|EventDate              |to_timestamp(`EventDate`, 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS')|
+-----------------------+----------------------------------------------------+
|2016/12/19 00:43:27.583|2016-12-19 00:43:27                                 |
+-----------------------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: any help plz    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55965978/how-to-set-jdbc-partitioncolumn-type-to-date-in-spark-2-4-1/55966481#55966481

Comment: What what if we want to parse multiple timestampformats in the same file, for example, in my csv file I have some timestamps like "dd/MM/yyyy" and like "dd-mm-yyyy" and I want to be able to parse both as timestamp, I tried this .Option("TimeStampFormat", "dd/MM/yyyy, dd-MM-yyyy") but it doesnt work

Comment: @Pugnatore Won't work for inconsistent timestamp formats. You have to create a UDF to do the parsing yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I searched for this issue, and discovered the offical Github issue page https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv/pull/280 which has fixed a related bug for parsing data with custom date format. I reviewed some source codes, and according to the [code](https://github.com/HyukjinKwon/spark-csv/blob/160dd82adeb07ef389afb67daadf8a70177bc5a1/src/main/scala/com/databricks/spark/csv/CsvRelation.scala#L247) to find out your issue reason which is set `inferSchema` with the default value `false` as below.

> `inferSchema`: automatically infers column types. It requires one extra pass over the data and is **false by default**

Please change `inferSchema` with `true` for your date format `yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS` using `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: I modified my code as below and ran it. It is still producing the same error val df = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header","true").option("delimiter","|").option("mode","FAILFAST").option("inferSchema","true").option("dateFormat","yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS").schema(sourceSchemaStruct).load(sourceFile)