# spark read.csv incorrectly parsing timestamps

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, timestamp

I have a csv file `presence.csv` in my datalake :

```
TIME,RESULT,PARENTLOCALIZATIONCODE,PARENTNAME,SIGFOXID,STATUS
2018-12-10T00:06:14.5464070Z,OK,A,A,19A9BC,OFF_PERIOD
```

I tried to read it but the `TIME` column output is wrong :

```
data = sqlContext.read.csv(
    'presence.csv',
    header='true', 
    inferSchema= 'true',  
    sep=","
)

data.show(truncate=False)
+----------------------+------+----------------------+----------+--------+----------+
|TIME                  |RESULT|PARENTLOCALIZATIONCODE|PARENTNAME|SIGFOXID|STATUS    |
+----------------------+------+----------------------+----------+--------+----------+
|2018-12-10 01:37:18.07|OK    |A                     |A         |19A9BC  |OFF_PERIOD|
+----------------------+------+----------------------+----------+--------+----------+
```

I first thought about a time difference between my server and gmt time, but one is `00:06:14` and the other one is `01:37:18` so about `01:31` difference which is just weird.

Do you have any idea why this convertion happens ?

Comment: @pault at least, it seems to be consistent in terms of minute and secondes ... the hour difference results probably in server time (USA or Europe I guess)

Comment: you can specify the timestamp format, instead of spark default timestamp format spark.read.csv("b.csv",header=True,inferSchema=True,timestampFormat="yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:sss")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs for [`pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader), the default `timestampFormat` is:

- `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX` for spark version 2.2 and above
- `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ` for [spark version 2.1](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader)
- `None` for spark version 2.0  [which means trying to parse times and date by `java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf()` and `java.sql.Date.valueOf()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader)

The main problem with your data is that you have 3 extra values in the fraction of a second. So for this data you need use `timestampFormat="yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss:SSSSSSZZ"`

```python
data = spark.read.csv(
    'presence.csv',
    header='true', 
    inferSchema= 'true',  
    sep=",",
    timestampFormat="yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss:SSSSSSZZ"
)

data.show(truncate=False)
#+-----------------------+------+----------------------+----------+--------+----------+
#|TIME                   |RESULT|PARENTLOCALIZATIONCODE|PARENTNAME|SIGFOXID|STATUS    |
#+-----------------------+------+----------------------+----------+--------+----------+
#|2018-12-09 19:06:14.546|OK    |A                     |A         |19A9BC  |OFF_PERIOD|
#+-----------------------+------+----------------------+----------+--------+----------+
```

But as you can see here, the `TIME` column is being converted to local time (which on my system is GMT-4).

If this is not what you want, the "fix" depends on your spark version and is detailed in the answers on [Spark Strutured Streaming automatically converts timestamp to local time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48767008/spark-strutured-streaming-automatically-converts-timestamp-to-local-time).

If you applied version specific "fix", you'd see the following result:

```python
df.show(truncate=False)
#+-----------------------+------+----------------------+----------+--------+----------+
#|TIME                   |RESULT|PARENTLOCALIZATIONCODE|PARENTNAME|SIGFOXID|STATUS    |
#+-----------------------+------+----------------------+----------+--------+----------+
#|2018-12-10 00:06:14.546|OK    |A                     |A         |19A9BC  |OFF_PERIOD|
#+-----------------------+------+----------------------+----------+--------+----------+
```

---

References:

- [How to load CSVs with timestamps in custom format?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43293031/5858851)
- [Spark 2.2 Illegal pattern component: XXX java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern component: XXX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46434137/5858851)