# pyspark dataframe datetime format conversion while loading from csv file without specifying column names

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

In csv file, input format for some columns which are date time fields is "mm-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss". While loading the file in dataframe, it should automatically detect the columns which are datetime and change the column to datetime datatype

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43259485/how-to-load-csvs-with-timestamps-in-custom-format ?